# R loop within loop: built in functions

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, vectorization

In R, I have a vector, say vec = c(1,2,...10).

What I want to do is loop through the vector, and for each element apply a function that again involves looping through the vector. I can do it with for loops, but I want to do it with built in functions.

For a concrete example, I'd like to take each element of the vector, and take the sum of the numbers that are greater than the current element I'm looking at. Then I'd get a new vector of the same length.

```
vec=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
newvec=c()

for (i in 1:10){

x=vec[i]
sum=0

for (j in 1:10){

if (vec[j]>x){
  sum=sum+vec[j]
}}
newvec=c(newvec,sum)}
newvec
```

What's the best way to accomplish this with built in functions, hopefully that applies even more generally than this example (e.g. multiple conditions being compared, not just vec[j]>x)? Any help is appreicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sapply`. For each element of `vec` (say `x`), it returns the `sum` of values of `vec` that are greater than `x`.

```r
sapply(vec, \(x) sum(vec[vec > x]))
# [1] 54 52 49 45 40 34 27 19 10  0
```

Comment: Thanks! What if there are additional conditions; add one value of vec>x , another if vec<x for example?

Comment: You can probably use `ifelse` for that, the inline version of `if/else`. You can change the function inside `sapply` at will (starting with `\(x)`).

Comment: @user352188 the `\(x)` in Mael's answer defines an anonymous function.  that function can be as complex or simple as you require.  Approaches for the additional conditions might be `if...else` constructs, the `ifelse()` one-liner version of that construct, a `switch()` statement if you have more conditions etc.